# React NPM Run Build Only Rendering Index Page

Tags: reactjs, npm, netlify, npm-run

I am trying to deploy a simple React portfolio site to Netlify. I tried last night to deploy via Github and I kept receiving errors. I have now started attempting to use NPM Run Build and dropping the build folder to Netlify to get the site up. This works fine for the home page but for the two other pages I have I get this message when navigating to them. "Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site." I know that NPM Run build is only for static sites but I thought you could navigate to other pages. I am using React Router for the navigation. Everything works fine on local host obviously, any help is appreciated.

Here is my App.js files with the routes.

```
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { Projects } from "./pages/Projects";
import { About } from "./pages/About";
import "./styles/styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="body">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects></Projects>}></Route>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About></About>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the home page that is rendering fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";
import { Header } from "../components/Header";
import { Footer } from "../components/Footer";
export const Home = () => {
 return (
   <>
     <Navbar />
     <Header />
     <Footer />
   </>
 );
};
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.17.1",
    "npm": "8.15.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "serve -s build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more of your App.js or whatever contains the routes? There isn't enough context here to be able to help yet.

Comment: Wesley, thank you for taking time to help me out. I updated to add my entire App.jsx as well as my Home.jsx which is correctly rendering.

Comment: For Starters  <Route path="/" element={<Home></Home>}></Route> I think you should fix this make it self closing

Comment: Thank you, I did that and no luck also removed the brackets from the imports in the App.jsx

Comment: I am starting to think it may be a Netlify issue. Whenever I use the commands `npm install -g serve
  serve -s build` both load and navigate pages fine. Does that sound right that it is a Netlify issue?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you created a `_redirects` file (no extension, it's plaintext) to contain a rule to direct to your React app:

`/*    /index.html   200`

They mention this on their blog post for [How to deploy React Apps in less than 30 seconds](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/)